# React Router V4 is updating URL, but not refreshing (React, Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I am trying to use React-Router V4 to add routes to my app, but it is not working at all. Basically, I'm trying to programatically change the route with `history.push`, which is updating the browser URL, but not changing anything inside the actual app.

NOTE: I am using redux.

The only answered question on this issue is:

[React history.push() is updating url but not navigating to it in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941708/react-history-push-is-updating-url-but-not-navigating-to-it-in-browser)

However, I've tried the answer to the above question, and it doesn't work for me.

Here are the important snippets:

**Topmost file (index.js)**

```html
...
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App/>
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
...
```

**Component containing routes**

```html
...
export default function ContentRouter() {
    return <div className="content">
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={TmpDashboard}/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={() => {
            return <h1>Home</h1>
        }}/>
    </div>
}
```

**Component pushing routes**

```html
...
this.handleGroupClick = (group) => {
    this.props.history.push(`/groups/${group}`);
    this.props.onOpenChange(false);
};
...
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(DrawerConnector))
```

Comment: Here's one: `this.props.history.push`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Comment: @admcfajn That is the one I am trying right now

Comment: I do not see DrawerConnector in ContentRouter. Where is it being used? Is it nested inside one of these components? I have found it useful to use withRouter on my top level component and do <Route component="fooComponent" /> inside it. For THEIR nested components, I pass history as props. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Hossein does DrawerConnector have to be nested inside the route? I though it only has to be nested inside the router

Comment: @AJC Yep it does. I went through this exact issue with my sidebar which was inside <BrowserHistory> but not wrapped in a higher order Router and it wouldn't work even though history was being passed to it.

Comment: @Hossein could you add an answer explaining with some example code? Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a lot of searching in the completely wrong place, I figured out what was wrong. The lack of updating was being caused by **Redux**

Whenever a component is wrapped in `connect` it causes updates to be blocked, and the view doesn't update.

The solution is mentioned here:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4671#issuecomment-285320076

Basically, every component with a `Route` or a React-Router thing inside it must be wrapped with `withRouter`

**EDIT: Only the top level component that uses `connect` should be wrapped in `withRouter`. Note that this may cause performance issues**

EDIT: The way I got around the increased coupling was to have a component just to deal with routes. That way, I only need to wrap that component, and the component with a Router.

Comment: While that would work, it'd be quite intrusive. You shouldn't have to wrap every single component with a WithRouter. I suggest you look at my answer for a less coupled version. Nevertheless, happy you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a setup that works:

The main App:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                   /* this is a common component and happens to need to redirect */
                   <Route component={CommonComponentThatPushesToHistory} />
                   <div id="body">
                       /* I usually place this switch in a separate Routes file */
                       <Switch>
                           <Route exact path="FooRoute" component={FooPage}/>
                           <Route exact path="BarRoute" component={BarPage}/>
                        </Switch>
                   </div>
                   /* another common component which does not push to history */
                   <Footer />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

CommonComponentThatPushesToHistory

```
class CommonComponentThatPushesToHistory extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <button type="button" 
                onClick={() => {this.props.history.push('some-page');}}>
                Click to get redirected</button>
        );
    }
}
```

FooPage may have a child component that pushes to history:

```
class FooPage extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <MyChild history={this.props.history} />
        );
    }
}
```

Then MyChild component can push to history the same way CommonComponentThatPushesToHistory does.