# Global error handler react/redux saga and redirect outside components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I am working on a React application that uses `redux-saga`.

I am a bit stuck on this so I am reaching out for some help/guidance.

I am trying to implement a global error handler, the goal is that every time the api sends back a `500` user should be redirected to a 500 page.

I thought a good way to do this was to use `axios interceptors`

This is my interceptor (skimmed down, to bare minimum):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import history from '../components/history'; // this is trouble

export default {
  configureAxios: (store) => {
    // Add a response interceptor
    axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
      // will work on this later
      return response;
      }, (error) => {
      // catches if the session ended!
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
    axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (error) => {
      // still very much work in progress
      if (error.response.status >= 500) {
        // maybe fire off an action to update the store
        history.push('/500');
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
   }
 };
```

Is this a good approach?

If it is, I have a problem where `history.push` does update the url but doesn't redirect to the page. I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620092/react-router-v4-is-updating-url-but-not-refreshing-react-redux) but couldn't get it to work.
Since it's using `react-router-dom` v4 I though to follow what is suggested [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-do-i-access-the-history-object-outside-of-components)

Installed history with `npm i history --save`
I created my `history.js`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

and then in `root.js`

```
import history from './history';
//some stuff here
const App = ({ matchedRoutes }) =>
<div>
  <Head />
  <Header />
  <Switch>
    {matchedRoutes.map((route, i) =>
      <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />
    )}
  </Switch>
  <Main />
</div>;

const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App matchedRoutes={routes} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? any suggestion on how to better implement this?

Comment: so for history not working.. solution is here https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1913. I needed to change `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; to `import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
` but I am not sure of the broader implications...