# Component is not getting rendered after history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, history.js

On a button click, I am getting the URL changed by doing `history.push()`

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'  
const history = createHistory()  
.  
. some code  
.  
history.push(`/share/${objectId}`)
```

and hoping the component mentioned in the `Route` for that URL would render but that is not happening. Though, on refreshing that component is getting rendered as expected. But I don't get that why it is not rendering as soon as the URL is changing. I've tried wrapping the component inside `withRouter`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'  
import {BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'  
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'  

import Home from './pages/home'  
import ViewFile from './pages/view-file'  

const history = createHistory()

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

      render() {
      return (
          <BrowserRouter>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}/>
                  <Route path={'/share/:id'} component={withRouter(ViewFile)}/>
              </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
      )
  }
}

export default App
```

as well as passing *history* in `Router` which I think same as using `BrowserRouter`.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'  
import {BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'  
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'  

import Home from './pages/home'  
import ViewFile from './pages/view-file'  

const history = createHistory()

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

      render() {
      return (
          <Router history={history}>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}/>
                  <Route path={'/share/:id'} component={ViewFile}/>
              </Switch>
          </Router>
      )
  }
}

export default App
```

but not getting any luck with this. Can anyone explain why is this happening?
*P.S I went through the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941708/react-history-push-is-updating-url-but-not-navigating-to-it-in-browser) but they didn't help*

Comment: Can you paste more code regarding the place where you call: history.push(`/share/${objectId}`)

Comment: which version of react router?

Comment: @Sujit.WarrierIt's 4.3.1

Comment: Also see: [React App showing empty page when redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're creating new history each time you invoke `createHistory()`. If you're using `react-router-dom` you can simply use the `withRouter` HOC that'll supply the `history` object to the component via a `prop`. You'll then utilize `history.push('/')`, or if it's in a `class component`, `this.props.history.push('/')` and so on.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/p694ln9j0

**routes** (define `history` within `routes`)

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import About from "../components/About";
import Contact from "../components/Contact";
import ScrollIntoView from "../components/ScrollIntoView";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <ScrollIntoView>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Header />
      </ScrollIntoView>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

**components/Header.js** (we want to access `history`, however, sometimes we have to use `withRouter` because components like `Header` don't reside within a `<Route "/example" component={Header}/>` HOC, so it's unaware of our routing)

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = ({ history }) => (
  <header>
    <nav style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/")}>Home</button>
        </li>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/about")}>About</button>
        </li>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/contact")}>Contact</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
);

export default withRouter(Header);
```

**components/Home.js** (a component like `Home` is aware of routing and has the `history` object already passed in via the `<Route path="/" component={Home} />` HOC, so `withRouter` isn't required)

```
import React from "react";

const Home = ({ history }) => (
  <div className="container">
    <button
      className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
      onClick={() => history.push("/notfound")}
    >
      Not Found
    </button>
    <p>
      ...
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

---

Same concept as above, however, if you don't want to use `withRouter`, then you can simply create a `history` instance that'll be shared across your components that need it. You'll `import` this `history` instance and navigate with `history.push('/');` and so on.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/5ymj657k1k

**history** (define `history` in its own file)

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

**routes** (import `history` into `routes`)

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import About from "../components/About";
import Contact from "../components/Contact";
import ScrollIntoView from "../components/ScrollIntoView";
import history from "../history";

export default () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <ScrollIntoView>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Header />
      </ScrollIntoView>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

**components/Header.js** (import `history` into `Header`)

```
import React from "react";
import history from "../history";

const Header = () => (
  <header>
    <nav style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/")}>Home</button>
        </li>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/about")}>About</button>
        </li>
        <li style={{ display: "inline", marginRight: 20 }}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/contact")}>Contact</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
);

export default Header;
```

**components/Home.js** (is still aware of routing and has the `history` object already passed in via the `<Route path="/" component={Home} />` HOC, so importing `history` isn't required, but you can still import it if you wanted to -- just don't deconstruct `history` in the `Home`'s function parameters)

```
import React from "react";

const Home = ({ history }) => (
  <div className="container">
    <button
      className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
      onClick={() => history.push("/notfound")}
    >
      Not Found
    </button>
    <p>
      ...
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

---

But you might be thinking, what about `BrowserRouter`? Well, `BrowserRouter` has it's own internal `history` object. We can, once again, use `withRouter` to access its `history`. In this case, we don't even need to `createHistory()` at all!

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/ko8pkzvx0o

**routes**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import About from "../components/About";
import Contact from "../components/Contact";
import Notfound from "../components/Notfound";
import ScrollIntoView from "../components/ScrollIntoView";

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <ScrollIntoView>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route component={Notfound} />
        </Switch>
        <Header />
      </ScrollIntoView>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I wasted hours yesterday in reading the docs of react router but didn't understand much. I think you should have written the docs.

Comment: It's not working, i have no idea why, i'm using `Router` not `BrowserRouter` but all my components are not rendering, the URL change but i always get the `404` fallback route component.

Comment: @HassanAzzam Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your example code.

Comment: It's the exact same code above, and it's not working i even tried `history.listen` and it returns `undefined` when i change routes.

Comment: @HassanAzzam It looks they may have dropped support for using your own history object in v5. When this was written, v4.x.x was the latest, and as such, it works as [expected](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-spence-lhczz). I'd encourage you to move away from this approach as there are other better alternatives (like using `BrowserRouter` with either the `useHistory` hook or accessing `history` with the `withRouter` higher order component if you're not using hooks)

Comment: Or... if you're using `redux`, then use [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), which allows you to `push` or `replace` items in history from anywhere.

Comment: Ya i know, but the problem is i wanted to use it outside a component, and `useHistory` only works inside a component.
But anyway thanks for the clarification you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: check version of react , react-router, react-router-dom and history package version that is  also impotent

Comment: I just wonder, why these things are not standaridized. Why everyone has to struggle.

Answer (score 18):

This may help someone. Make sure the `history` package version are compatible with the `react-router-dom`.

This combination **didn't** work for me:

history: `5.0.0` with react-router-dom: `5.2.0`

This combo **did**:

history: `4.10.1` with react-router-dom `5.2.0`

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue.

Comment: +1 this worked for me. I had history in v 5.0.0 and react-router-dom in 5.2.0 exact same!!! Thanks! Saved my day ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Spent the whole day looking for this answer!!!

Comment: thanks! it worked like a charm

Answer (score 9):

use `import { Router }` instead of `import { BrowserRouter as Router }` .
 Because BrowserRouter ignores the history prop.

Comment: Wow! That was it! So many hours trying to find this! The `history.push()` works just like that with `Router`.

Comment: Wow way easier than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Setting BrowserRouter prod forceRefresh to true works as well.  `<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>`

Answer (score 4):

**Few points:**

1) Use `import { Router} from 'react-router-dom'` rather than `import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'`

2) Create variable `history` in a different file namely (can be changed) `../src/services/history.js` and the content should be :

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
const history = createBrowserHistory();
export default history;
```

You would have to install the `react-history` package by `npm install --save react-history`

3) Import history into main file and pass that inside the Router component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import history from './services/history'


class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage}></Route>
                    <Route exact path='/vendor' component={VendorPage}></Route>
                    <Route exact path='/client' component={ClientPage}></Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

4) Now you can use `history` anywhere in the components by

```
import React from 'react'
import history from '../services/history';

export default class VendorPage extends React.Component {

    loginUser = () => {
        if (<SOME_CONDITION>)
            history.push('/client')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Welcome to Vendor Page....</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope it Helps..

:)

Comment: I think he can the `useHistory()` hook of  `react-router-dom`, so that he won't have to install an another library.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seems to work any longer

Comment: This does not work the expected way for `react-router-dom v6`

Answer (score 3):

check version of react , react-router, react-router-dom and history package version that is also impotent –
my config package.json

```
"history": "^4.10.1",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-router": "5.1.2",
"react-router-dom": "5.1.2"
```

check this link :-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-34ohqv?embed=1&file=package.json
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-router-example-mahi-hzitgg?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: Spent 3 hours to why history wasn't working, This was the reason. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly!!! For some reason history version 5 doesn't work! When I downgraded to the version suggested worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For **people using hooks**, using `useLocation()` hook instead of `useHistory()` worked.

```
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
```

Component re-renders each time pathname changes.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading history package to history: 4.10.1 with react-router-dom 5.2.0 works for me

Comment: [React App showing empty page when redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985293/2873538)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
import { useHistory, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

let history = useHistory();
let match = useRouteMatch();
```